# How to effectively handle errors in Teamcenter ITK C++ code

Tags: c++, error-handling, teamcenter, teamcenter-itk

How do I effectively handle errors thrown by ITK calls in Teamcenter server customization code?

In the C ITK APIs, a function typically returns an integer value to denote success/failure. Zero (`ITK_ok`) is typically treated as success and non-zero is treated as failure. In case of a failure, the developer must cleanup resources used (e.g., free memory).

I have seen a lot of code written by customization developers using a macro. Even I did that when I first wrote my first Teamcenter ITK program:

```c
#define ITK(A) { \
    iFail = A; \
    if (iFail != ITK_ok) { \
        HANDLE THE ERROR \
    } \
}
```

I defined a macro like that and used it everywhere I made an ITK function call. For example:

```c
ITK(AOM_ask_value_logical(myTag, "attributeName", &attributeValue));
```

It compares the output of every function call with `ITK_ok` and does something. There is nothing wrong with it. But many things could actually go wrong, and it can difficult to understand.

I have even seen people doing this:

```c
if (ITK_ok != AOM_ask_value_logical(myTag, "attributeName", &attributeValue))
{
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Or

```
int result = ITK_ok
result = AOM_ask_value_logical( myTag, "attributeName", &attributeValue);
if (ITK_ok != result)
{
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

I mean, there is nothing wrong with this one. But doesn’t it increase your code size? Don’t you see the duplicity?

Later, I realized that we could do this in more elegant simple way. C++ way using classes and overloaded operator. And later I even found that there is something called as `ResultCheck` in OOTB (out-of-the-box) Teamcenter.

All you need to do is include a header file and use a class from it.

```c
#include <base_utils/ResultCheck.hxx>
```

This file declares the `ResultCheck` class with overloaded assignment operator. This file is included in Teamcenter kit, you can have a look.

It does a very small and neat task. With this, my earlier statement gets converted to the below.

```c
ResultCheck rCheck = ITK_ok;
try
{
    rCheck = AOM_ask_value_logical( myTag, "attributeName", &attributeValue);
}
catch (const IFail &ex)
{
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

With every function call return statement, an instance of `ResultCheck` is created. If you check the header file, you would see overloaded assignment operator takes an `ifail` (integer) as an input. Internally it checks if `ifail` is `ITK_ok` or not. If it is not, then it simply throws `IFail`. And control is passed to you in catch block to do anything you want to do.

Simple isn’t it? So let’s now remove all these macros and use this…

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you try to answer your own question - please adopt the Q&A format of this site and post the question part as a specific question and the answer part as an answer.

Comment: i tried to find it in stackoverflow. but i couldn't find it. and then i found solution as well. then how do i post it?

Comment: Please use the ->[edit]<- link to update your question - don't post updates or additional info as separate answers. This site isn't a forum in the way you may be used to.

Comment: thanks. :)  i didn't know this.

Comment: If you want to salvage the question you should probably set as title "_How do I most effectively handle errors thrown by ITKs in Teamcenter server customization?_", add an answer telling right away about the "ResultCheck.hxx" stuff and then if you want in a separate "Background" section of the answer put (some of) the rest of what's currently in the question. The body of the edited question itself might even be left blank, the title seems to say enough. Also add more appropriate tags, for sure at least `error-handling`.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I didn't see the existing answer. If you do what I said but merging the "ResultCheck.hxx" stuff into the existing answer instead of posting a new one you could turn this into a decent question.

Answer (score 2):

There is similar ResultStatus class which does the same.

```
#include <base_utils/TcResultStatus.hxx>
```

and sample code would be like

```
ResultStatus rStatus = ITK_ok;
try
{
     rStatus = AOM_ask_value_logical( myTag, "attributeName", &attriubuteValue);
}
catch(const IFail &ex)
{
     // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that with ResultCheck, whenever it detects anything other than an ITK_ok, it adds that error code onto the top of the error stack data structure as well. So you should take a call on whether to clear that data structure before you exit from the method.